# Interpreting request as JSP instead of through servlet

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, jboss

This should be relatively simple to do but I've yet to find a description of how to do it.

My setup is a simple web app that processes every request through a servlet (I'll call it MyEverythingServlet for this question). Here's a slightly modified version of my web.xml:

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>MyEverythingServlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>blah.blah.blah.MyEverythingServlet</servlet-class>
</servlet>

<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>MyEverythingServlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Right now, the servlet is pretty simple and either does some work (when work.do is part of the path) and if a .txt file is specified in the path, we'll do some validation and then load the file and send the text as the response:

```
response.getOutputStream().print( content );
```

What I'd like to do is either:

- Inside the servlet, if the request is a URL to a .jsp file, I'd like to be able to have the container interpret the JSP scriptlet parts/taglib stuff before I write the String to the response.
- Change my web.xml to have it process .jsp files outside of MyEverythingServlet.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> - Inside the servlet, if the request is a URL to a .jsp file, I'd like to be able to have the container interpret the JSP scriptlet parts/taglib stuff before I write the String to the response.

There's no direct API available which processes JSP files programmatically like that. In theory, you'd like to have the JSP in public webcontent and **forward** the request to the JSP. You can do this with `RequestDispatcher#forward()`.

```
if (request.getServletPath().endsWith(".jsp")) {
    request.getRequestDispatcher(request.getServletPath()).forward(request, response);
} else {
    // Write "plain" to response as you did.
}
```

You may only want to do some checks on the correctness of the paths, but this should at least give you the generic idea. There is however a little problem: the servlet will be invoked recursively since it's mapped on `/*`. You'd rather replace this `MyEverythingServlet` by a `Filter` which just delegates the remnant of the job to the appserver's builtin default servlet. Having a `Servlet` to listen on `/*` is already a design-smell indication that it should have been a `Filter` from the beginning on ;)

> - Change my web.xml to have it process .jsp files outside of MyEverythingServlet.

You can't have a "negative" `url-pattern` in `web.xml`. Best what you can do is to let the servlet listen on a more specific `url-pattern` like `*.txt` or `/static/*` and keep the JSP files there outside.

Comment: Are you suggesting I use filter and filter-mapping instead of servlet-mapping in my web.xml file? Then I'd have the filter look for *.jsp and do nothing for those requests (chain.doFilter() )? How would the Filter send non-JSP requests to the MyEverythingServlet?

Comment: You can also do so (only if those non-JSP files are outside public webcontent and you're forced to use `FileInputStream` or so to read them). You should then map the servlet on a more specific `url-pattern` and dispatch the request using an URL matching this pattern (I'd in turn question the value of the Filter.. ;) ). But if those files are in public webcontent, then just continuing filter chain is enough. The servletcontainer's builtin default servlet will serve the non-JSP file up for you.

Comment: Ok, I think the only piece I'm missing is how the Filter will forward the request on to the MyEverythingServlet.

Comment: E.g. `request.getRequestDispatcher("/servletURL" + request.getServletPath()).forward(request, response);` whereby the `MyEverythingServlet` is mapped on `/servletURL/*` (change to your taste). But on the other hand, you can also just change the existing URL's to match this servlet without the need to have it passed through a filter :)

Comment: Sorry, I should have added that the `getServletPath()` method can only be accessed in the `Filter` after downcasting the `ServletRequest` argument to `HttpServletRequest`. If you want a more complete URL (i.e. including root folders), you can also use `getRequestURI()`.